# Jsch OutputStream not showing the full server output using Java

Tags: java, outputstream, jsch

I am using JSCH to run multiple commands on a server. everything works but I am having an issue capturing the server response if the command's output is long. If the command's output is long, the outputStream only shows what normaly gets displayed via a putty session and in order to see the full output you have to hit enter to move between the lines or q to exit.

```
A Sample of a long server response that you need to hit enter to continue.
```

[image]

Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JSchException, InterruptedException, IOException {

        extractResources();
        TMPFS jssh = new TMPFS();

        // Local class for feeding commands to a pipe in a background thread.
        class CommandSender
                implements Runnable {

            private final OutputStream target;

            IOException exception;

            CommandSender(OutputStream target) {
                this.target = Objects.requireNonNull(target);
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (String command : commands) {
                        target.write(command.getBytes());
                        target.write(10);   // newline
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    exception = e;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted, exiting prematurely.");
                }
            }
        }

       try (OutputStream logout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath))) {
            try (InputStream login = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(outputFilePath))) {

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            if (!hosts.isEmpty() && user != null && password != null) {

                for (String host : hosts) {
                    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
                    session.setPassword(password);
                    session.setConfig(getProperties());
                    session.connect(10 * 1000);
                    if (session.isConnected()) {
                        System.out.println(session.getHost() + " Connected");
                    }

                    Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
channel.setInputStream(login, true);
channel.setOutputStream(logout, true);

                    try (PipedInputStream commandSource = new PipedInputStream();
                            OutputStream commandSink = new PipedOutputStream(commandSource)) {

                        CommandSender sender = new CommandSender(commandSink);
                        Thread sendThread = new Thread(sender);
                        sendThread.start();

                        channel.setInputStream(commandSource);
                        channel.connect(15 * 1000);
                        System.out.println("Commands executed: \n" + session.getHost() + " disconnected");
                        sendThread.join();
                        if (sender.exception != null) {
                            throw sender.exception;
                        }
                    }

                    channel.disconnect();
                    session.disconnect();
                    if (!session.isConnected()) {
                        System.out.println("Commands executed \n" + session.getHost() + " disconnected");
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: You are executing the `more` command. Solution: don't.

Comment: updated the Image, I get line 1 of something that I have to keep hitting enter.